# How to assign a numerical value to multiple cells and then add those values in a separate cell

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I'd like to assign a value of $20 to a cell if 'Yes' is the text in the cell. I'd like to have a row of cells with this, each with the same value and I'd like then to be able to sum the total value of all these cells for each one that has 'yes' as text in them. If the cells D3 - H3 each have this assignment, then if D3 and G3 have 'yes' in them, my total at the end of the row should show '40' or $40 (as I'd like to add them up as currency). How might this be accomplished? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

This should be all you need:

```
=COUNTIF(D3:H3,"Yes")*20
```